# WinForms colours on Servers

Tags: c#, winforms, color-scheme

I have a winForms app that uses Black Button text, when in use on 'normal' machines (IE: Anything but a server) the text in black. However when we put it on a server, the text is white?

This is because the server uses Windows Basic Colour scheme. Is there anything I can do in my code to change this? (Without affecting the colours on normal machines?)-I've been searching around and can't seem to find anything on this subject?

-As well as text colour, tabs look totally different too, instead of the 'Control' back colour they have reverted to white?

Is the only resolution to change the server colour scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `ForeColor` of button will be `SystemColors.ControlText` which is a system parameter, If you don't want that you can always set it to `Color.Black`. It will not vary across systems.